# environment variable set in make not seen by all sub-shells

Tags: variables, makefile, environment

I need to set env variables in a makefile and use them in a python script invoked by the makefile. For some reason the python script is not able to see these env variables.

```
export VAR := env_var
PY_VAR := python -c "import os; print('VAR=' + str(os.environ.get('VAR')))"

all:
    @echo -n "echoing: VAR="
    @echo $${VAR}
    @echo -n "printenv: "
    @printenv | grep VAR
    @echo -n "python: "
    @echo $(shell ${PY_VAR})
```

Output:

```
echoing: VAR=env_var
printenv: VAR=env_var
python: VAR=None
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most versions of GNU make, variable exported from the makefile are passed to *recipes* but they are not passed to the `shell` function.

Only in the very latest version of GNU make (4.4 and above), you will see exported variables passed to `shell`.

In general it's wrong / a bad idea to use `shell` in a recipe.  It's totally unnecessary because a recipe is *already* running in a shell.

If you run `PY_VAR` explicitly rather than using make's `shell` function, it will work:

```
PY_VAR := python -c "import os; print('VAR=' + str(os.environ.get('VAR')))"

all:
        @echo $$(${PY_VAR})
```

Comment: In the above example, is it somehow possible to evaluate PY_VAR before the recipe (i.e. as a variable) and without using $(shell ) so the above recipe "all" should simply be @echo ${PYVAR}?

Comment: No.  The only way make will invoke a shell is either through a recipe, or with the `shell` function.  If that's what you wanted to do it would have been helpful if that's what your example did: we can't describe the right way to do things when we don't know what you actually want to do.  In that case you'll have to set the variable directly in the `shell` function call: `PY_VAR := $(shell VAR='$(VAR)' python -c ...)`